# rastertospl failed - Samsung ML2165

Tags: linux, printing, cups

I'm using CUPS on my Raspberry to print to my laser printer Samsung ML-2165.

I installed the samsung unified linux driver without issues, but when I try to print something, I get

```
/usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertospl failed
```

I did check the error log, and this is the produced output:

```
E [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] Job stopped due to filter errors; please consult the error_log file for details.
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] The following messages were recorded from 18:06:04 to 18:06:14
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] Adding start banner page "none".
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] Adding end banner page "none".
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] File of type text/plain queued by "Harlandraka".
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] hold_until=0
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] Queued on "Samsung_ML-2160_Series" by "Harlandraka".
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] job-sheets=none,none
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] argv[0]="Samsung_ML-2160_Series"
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] argv[1]="7"
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] argv[2]="Harlandraka"
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] argv[3]="city.php"
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] argv[4]="1"
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] argv[5]="job-uuid=urn:uuid:fb316d9e-b5ef-3983-460e-32a45972eaa9 job-originating-host-name=192.168.0.200 time-at-creation=1417889164 time-at-processing=1417889164"
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] argv[6]="/var/spool/cups/d00007-001"
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] envp[0]="CUPS_CACHEDIR=/var/cache/cups"
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] envp[1]="CUPS_DATADIR=/usr/share/cups"
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] envp[2]="CUPS_DOCROOT=/usr/share/cups/doc-root"
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] envp[3]="CUPS_FONTPATH=/usr/share/cups/fonts"
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] envp[4]="CUPS_REQUESTROOT=/var/spool/cups"
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] envp[5]="CUPS_SERVERBIN=/usr/lib/cups"
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] envp[6]="CUPS_SERVERROOT=/etc/cups"
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] envp[7]="CUPS_STATEDIR=/var/run/cups"
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] envp[8]="HOME=/var/spool/cups/tmp"
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] envp[9]="PATH=/usr/lib/cups/filter:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin"
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] envp[10]="SERVER_ADMIN=root@raspberrypi"
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] envp[11]="SOFTWARE=CUPS/1.5.3"
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] envp[12]="TMPDIR=/var/spool/cups/tmp"
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] envp[13]="TZ=Etc/UTC"
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] envp[14]="USER=root"
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] envp[15]="CUPS_SERVER=/var/run/cups/cups.sock"
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] envp[16]="CUPS_ENCRYPTION=IfRequested"
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] envp[17]="IPP_PORT=631"
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] envp[18]="CHARSET=utf-8"
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] envp[19]="LANG=en_US.UTF-8"
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] envp[20]="PPD=/etc/cups/ppd/Samsung_ML-2160_Series.ppd"
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] envp[21]="RIP_MAX_CACHE=128m"
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] envp[22]="CONTENT_TYPE=text/plain"
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] envp[23]="DEVICE_URI=usb://Samsung/ML-2160%20Series?serial=Z7CYBKCC105443N"
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] envp[24]="PRINTER_INFO=Samsung ML-2160 Series"
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] envp[25]="PRINTER_LOCATION="
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] envp[26]="PRINTER=Samsung_ML-2160_Series"
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] envp[27]="PRINTER_STATE_REASONS=none"
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] envp[28]="CUPS_FILETYPE=document"
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] envp[29]="FINAL_CONTENT_TYPE=printer/Samsung_ML-2160_Series"
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] envp[30]="AUTH_I****"
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] Started filter /usr/lib/cups/filter/texttopdf (PID 17755)
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] Started filter /usr/lib/cups/filter/pdftopdf (PID 17756)
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] Started filter /usr/lib/cups/filter/gstoraster (PID 17757)
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] Started filter /usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertospl (PID 17758)
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] Started backend /usr/lib/cups/backend/usb (PID 17759)
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] Printing on printer with URI: usb://Samsung/ML-2160%20Series?serial=Z7CYBKCC105443N
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] libusb_get_device_list=6
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] STATE: +connecting-to-device
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] STATE: -connecting-to-device
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] Printer found with device ID: MFG:Samsung;CMD:SPL,FWV,PIC,EXT;MDL:ML-2160 Series;CLS:PRINTER;MODE:SPL5,R0STATUS:BUSY; Device URI: usb://Samsung/ML-2160%20Series?serial=Z7CYBKCC105443N
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] Device protocol: 2
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] Sending data to printer.
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] Set job-printer-state-message to "Sending data to printer.", current level=INFO
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] Page = 595x842; 12,12 to 582,830
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] Sent 0 bytes...
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] PPD uses qualifier 'Gray.None.600dpi'
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] Calling FindDeviceById(Samsung_ML-2160_Series)
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] Failed to send: org.freedesktop.ColorManager.Failed:device id 'Samsung_ML-2160_Series' does not exists
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] Failed to get profile filename!
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] no profiles specified in PPD
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] Ghostscript command line: /usr/bin/gs -dQUIET -dPARANOIDSAFER -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dNOINTERPOLATE -sDEVICE=cups -sstdout=%stderr -sOutputFile=%stdout -r600x600 -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=595 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=842 -dcupsBitsPerColor=8 -dcupsColorOrder=0 -dcupsColorSpace=0 -scupsPageSizeName=A4 -I/usr/share/cups/fonts -c -f -_
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] envp[0]="CUPS_CACHEDIR=/var/cache/cups"
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] envp[1]="CUPS_DATADIR=/usr/share/cups"
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] envp[2]="CUPS_DOCROOT=/usr/share/cups/doc-root"
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] envp[3]="CUPS_FONTPATH=/usr/share/cups/fonts"
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] envp[4]="CUPS_REQUESTROOT=/var/spool/cups"
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] envp[5]="CUPS_SERVERBIN=/usr/lib/cups"
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] envp[6]="CUPS_SERVERROOT=/etc/cups"
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] envp[7]="CUPS_STATEDIR=/var/run/cups"
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] envp[8]="HOME=/var/spool/cups/tmp"
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] envp[9]="PATH=/usr/lib/cups/filter:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin"
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] envp[10]="SERVER_ADMIN=root@raspberrypi"
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] envp[11]="SOFTWARE=CUPS/1.5.3"
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] envp[12]="TMPDIR=/var/spool/cups/tmp"
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] envp[13]="TZ=Etc/UTC"
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] envp[14]="USER=root"
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] envp[15]="CUPS_SERVER=/var/run/cups/cups.sock"
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] envp[16]="CUPS_ENCRYPTION=IfRequested"
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] envp[17]="IPP_PORT=631"
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] envp[18]="CHARSET=utf-8"
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] envp[19]="LANG=en_US.UTF-8"
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] envp[20]="PPD=/etc/cups/ppd/Samsung_ML-2160_Series.ppd"
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] envp[21]="RIP_MAX_CACHE=128m"
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] envp[22]="CONTENT_TYPE=text/plain"
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] envp[23]="DEVICE_URI=usb://Samsung/ML-2160%20Series?serial=Z7CYBKCC105443N"
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] envp[24]="PRINTER_INFO=Samsung ML-2160 Series"
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] envp[25]="PRINTER_LOCATION="
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] envp[26]="PRINTER=Samsung_ML-2160_Series"
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] envp[27]="PRINTER_STATE_REASONS=none"
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] envp[28]="CUPS_FILETYPE=document"
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] envp[29]="FINAL_CONTENT_TYPE=printer/Samsung_ML-2160_Series"
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] envp[30]="AUTH_INFO_REQUIRED=none"
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] Waiting for read thread to exit...
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] Start rendering...
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] Processing page 1...
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] Read thread still active, aborting the pending read...
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] Resetting printer.
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] End of messages
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] printer-state=3(idle)
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] printer-state-message="Processing page 1..."
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] printer-state-reasons=none
E [06/Dec/2014:18:11:15 +0000] [Job 7] Stopping unresponsive job!
```

I was focusing on these lines:

```
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] PPD uses qualifier 'Gray.None.600dpi'
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] Calling FindDeviceById(Samsung_ML-2160_Series)
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] Failed to send: org.freedesktop.ColorManager.Failed:device id 'Samsung_ML-2160_Series' does not exists
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] Failed to get profile filename!
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] no profiles specified in PPD
```

---

```
Failed to send: org.freedesktop.ColorManager.Failed:device id 'Samsung_ML-2160_Series' does not exists
```

How can this happen? I created the printer with CUPS, why does CUPS not find it?

```
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] Failed to get profile filename!
D [06/Dec/2014:18:06:14 +0000] [Job 7] no profiles specified in PPD
```

How should I define profiles? I'm using the PPDs provided by the Unified Linux Driver by Samsung, should I modify them?